# Data entry incorrect and duplication

Tags: sql-server

Im building a SQL server data base for a "school" i have multiple tables and primary keys linking between these tables. Ive now run into an weird issue that in one of the tables it duplicates data and has incorrect information. See below my code:

```
if not exists (select * from sysobjects where name='class' and xtype='U')
begin
  CREATE TABLE class
    (
    classcode varchar(3) not null,
    Teacher varchar(30) Not Null,
    Location varchar(30) Not Null,
    );

INSERT INTO class
VALUES ('1A','Mr Smith','4K');

Insert into class
values ('1B','Mr Jones','3F');

Insert into class
values ('2A','Ms Abbey','2D');

Insert into class
values ('2B','Mrs Dear','2B');

end;
```

What this should do is enter 4 rows with the correct values but for some reason im getting the following.

[[image: [1]]

As you can see i have more columns then ive actually written into the code. Ive deleted the database multiple times in case it had a saved temporary file which could include that information but it still persists.

My expected results are:

```
1A  Mr Smith    4K
1B  Mr Jones    3F
2A  Ms Abbey    2D
2B  Mrs Dear    2B
```

Comment: please post expected results as text

Comment: There is absolutely zero percent chance that the code you have provided creates the data you say it does. *Literally* zero percent! Apart from anything else where would it get `classcode` of `01`, `11` etc from exactly?

Comment: and your current results are :

Comment: ` i have deleted the database multiple times`delete again,run profiler and post profiler data

Comment: @Jamiec The code you see above is the only thing ive done to this table and it happens every time i execute my code. Ive restarted my machine, checked for linking issues etc but it still persists.

Comment: Just to humour you, I just ran your code against a local sql server new database and I get 4 rows of data as expected. There is something else going on! Open profiler, attach it and run your script and look what is *actually happening in your local environment*. Again, it is NOT the code you've posted here.

Comment: BTW, when you work out how this happened I'm intrigued to know. Do come back and comment (or, even better, answer your own question!)

Comment: @Jamiec I literally have no idea how it happened this is my first time using SQL im just going to scrap it and rebuild it fresh hoping that it wont replicate.